# Mi formulario se corta en la ultima pagina cuando lo transformo en pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, html2pdf, html2canvas

Estoy exportando mi formulario de mi pagina web a un pdf, si me genera el archivo pdf pero el problema es la ultima pagina, ya que corta a la mitad la ultima pagina, ya no me muestra lo demas del formulario, asi como en el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que no se cual seria el problema, en mi codigo para descargarlo como pdf es el siguiente

```
function descargarPDF(){
    html2pdf().set({
    filename: 'my-document.pdf',
    margin: 0.20,
    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.90 },
    html2canvas: {
        scale: 2,
        useCORS: true
    },
    jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
    pageBreak: {
        after: 'tr',
        before: 'tr',
        avoid: 'tr'
    }
}).from(componentRef.current).save().then((event) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log("Si se imprimio");
})}
```

Ya intente ajustar la escala del html2canvas pero no da resultados, pense que era mi componente de react pero igual no se arregla por lo que no se que se tendria que agregar para ajustarlo